# PHP Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in eval()'d code on line 1

Tags: php, laravel-5, entrust

I'm using [ENTRUST (Laravel 5 Package)](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/zizaco/entrust). When I use command `User::all();` in Php artisan tinker's Shell command line. It gives me error

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found in eval()'d code on line 1

but after trying 2-3 different combination(which are wrong) if I use the same `User::all();`, it gives me correct result. It looks weird.

I'm new to PHP as well as Laravel.

**User.php**

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    use EntrustUserTrait; // add this trait to your user model
}
```

Console output:

```
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 5.5.9 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> User::all();
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
>>> App/User::all();
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
>>> App\User::all();
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\User' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
>>> User::all();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#664
     all: [
       User {#665
         id: 1,
         name: "Kartik",
         email: "******************",
         password: "qwerty",
         remember_token: null,
         created_at: "2016-08-18 17:13:40",
         updated_at: "2016-08-18 17:13:40",
       },
       User {#666
         id: 2,
         name: "Bhandari",
         email: "**************",
         password: "qwerty",
         remember_token: null,
         created_at: "2016-08-20 11:37:26",
         updated_at: "2016-08-20 11:37:26",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

give the complete path for the modal i.e. with namespaces

```
project_namespace\Models\User::all()
```

Comment: Please correct spell mistake `project_namespace\Models\User::all()` method name is all() and not alll()